# What is an approach in computer vision that can be used for tracking players in hockey games?

Tags: computer-vision, machine-learning

It differs from human tracking in random environment in that detail that we have fixed environment. And players move pretty fast and it is important to resolve collisions and occlusions, keep track of right person. So please tell me what you think about this problem. Or what paper can be used to implement state-of-the-art approach for human tracking that you are aware of?

Comment: Your question has beeen answered. Do not hesitate to vote for the useful ones and accept the most suitable

Answer (score 1):

Regarding speed and occlusions, I would suggest you to take a look at this work on basketball: [Locate and Track People in a Network of Fixed Overlapping Cameras](http://www.ivpe.com/detectppl.htm), and notably published in A. Alahi, Y. Boursier, L. Jacques, and P. Vandergheynst. [Sparsity Driven People Localization with a Heterogeneous Network of Cameras](http://www.ivpe.com/papers/jmiv11.pdf), in Journal of Mathematical Imaging and Vision, 2011. Then by looking at its [citation network](https://scholar.google.fr/scholar?oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:fr:official&client=firefox-a&gfe_rd=cr&gws_rd=ssl&um=1&ie=UTF-8&lr&cites=16179636356775744338), you could find other relevant work.